# Trying to use Circuit Playground Express with iPad - CPLAYBOOT USB partition disappears due to "No valid file provider found"

Tags: ios, ipad, arduino, adafruit, makecode

I'm trying to connect my Circuit Playground Express (CPE) to my iPad using a Lightning to USB converter. The converter works fine with a standard USB flash drive. When I plug in the CPE the systme initially properly recognizes the drive label as CPLAYBOOT. If I'm quick I can even read the contents of the boot files.

However after about 2 seconds it disappears from the list of folders and is inaccessible.
I updated to UF2 bootloader to 3.10.0 but the problem persists. My iPad is running OS version 13.5.0.

When I'm quick enough to try copying a file to the CPE, I get the following message on the iPad:
"No valid file provider found for com.apple.../CPLAYBOOT."

Any solutions out there?

BTW my goal is to run makecode on the iPad and easily download the result to my CPE.

Comment: Hi did you ever resolve this issue? I'm also hoping to be able to program a Circuit Playground Express from iOS

Comment: See [this thread](https://forum.makecode.com/t/circuit-playground-express-on-mobile-devices/799/18) on Microsoft MakeCode forum as well

Comment: Sorry, no. But the other post implies that someone got it working.  Hope you find a solution.